# How attach two Click Listener in a button in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to attach two click listener in a button and both onclicklistener should be different. Is there any way to do this.? Can't use function to call from first to second. When I use this then I got output from second one only. I want both output.

*I am working on some screening task, so whenever a use click on a button it tell me that user clicked on this in Logcat and also button do its normal task.*

**First is :**

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Log.i("First Click" , "Clicked on button 1");
       }
 });
```

**Second is :**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v2) {
        if (v2 instanceof Button) {
            Log.i("User Clicked a checkbox with value ", " : " + ((Button) v2).getText().toString());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why you wanna do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am working on some screening task, so whenever a use click on a button it tell me that user clicked on this in Logcat and also button do its normal task.

Comment: And what other things you want to see in your logcat other than clicking this button? Do you mean that you will have other buttons or views that when clicked you want them to do their own work + show in your logcat what was clicked??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. Setting your second OnClickListener removes the first one.

That's why the function is called `setOnClickListener()` instead of `addOnClickListener()`

As you say, you can call two functions from the `onClick()`

Edit:

On your edit, you say that you want to show a message when your button is clicked.

You can add the loggging functionality that you need before doing anything else on the event, simply doing

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Log something

    // Your functionality
}
```

Or you can create a class implementing `View.OnClickListener`

```
public class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Log something
    }
}
```

And then, on your Activity:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        super.onClick(v);

        // Your functionality
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no way to do this.. ?

Comment: @Rishi Meena No, but I think that the problem is on your design. Why can't you use two functions? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am working on some screening task, so whenever a use click on a button it tell me that user clicked on this in Logcat and also button do its normal task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function in OnClickListener like-

```
       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       run1();
       run2();
      }
    });


private void run1(){
//Your first functionality
}


private void run2(){
//Your second functionality
}
```

Comment: that's the problem I can't use like this , due to some reason.

Comment: Then you have to explain what is your problem clearly. Why you can not use this. After that we can help you

Comment: I am working on some screening task, so whenever a use click on a button it tell me that user clicked on this in Logcat and also button do its normal task.

Comment: What is problem of using both these things in single onClick. First use the Log.i after that use your functionality

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you could do this:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    dothings(); //what you are trying to achieve with this button click
    showViewInLogCat(v); //to show you the view in the logcat
    }
}
```

where `showViewInLogCat()` is a function that show you which view was clicked in your logcat:

```
public void showViewInLogCat(View view) {

   if (view instanceof Button) {
      Log.i("User Clicked a checkbox with value ", " : " + ((Button) view).getText().toString());
   }
   //and add the other if
}
```

You can call this function in every `OnClick` event  on other views

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you want to do something like this..!

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("First Click" , "Clicked on button 1");
        // add a boolean here to check if you want to do the task or not.
        doTask = true;
        doGeneralTask(doTask); //to show you the view in the logcat
    }
}
```

and in `doGeneralTask(doTask)` do something like this.

```
public void doGeneralTask(boolean doTask) {

    if (doTask) {
      // do whatever generalized tasks you need.
    }

}
```